# how to make an array follow a strict form?

Tags: php, arrays

i have this specific array form i use in my functions

```
$array = [
  'x' => [
    0 => [
      'a' => '',
      'b' => ''
    ],
    ............
  ]
  'y' => [
    0 => [
      'a' => '',
      'b' => ''
    ],
    ............
  ]
];
```

this array is specified with

**first level** has only `'x'` and `'y'` keys

inside of them an array of **numeric keys** which can extendes to infinite

and inside these **numeric keys** two of **letters keys** `'a'` and `'b'` which their values is a **string**

this array is produced using `HTML` **input** using two inputs with values like this

```
value="array[x][][a]"
value="array[x][][b]"
value="array[y][][a]"
value="array[y][][b]"
```

which can be changed and submitted easily by changing any of the levels value like

```
value="array[z][z][z]"
```

and get a new level like

```
$array = [
  'z' => [
    'z' => [
       'z' =>  => ''
    ]
  ]
];
```

and i want to make it strict to only the specific first form of array in the beginning, i thought about using this

```
$correctForm = [
  'x' => [
    0 => [
      'a' => '',
      'b' => ''
    ],
    ............
  ]
  'y' => [
    0 => [
      'a' => '',
      'b' => ''
    ],
    ............
  ]
];
$array = array_intersect_key($array, $correctForm);
```

but the part of `numeric keys` and its values aren't strict enought in case i added another letter like `'c' => ''` it will still pass and also if i changed the key to a letter is gets passed too, so what i want to do is to strict this

level 1 `['x', 'z']` only

level 2 `numeric characters key` only

level 3 `['a', 'b']` only

can i do that?

Comment: You could always create a custom validation function to check your array to make sure it follows your standards.

Comment: @danwebb i used multiple `foreach()` to clean the array one by one but it does not seem the optimal way

Comment: The comment by David Lemon seems to be a good resource for your problem